# React: Trouble getting event target info from onmouseover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmouseover

Making a connect four game in React. I want a table box to highlight when hovered over and I'm unable to retrieve the information from the event. I'm able to log the event, but it's undefined.

The board squares are being generated in the main class component and passed to a function component to be rendered. I know this is the problem because all my other events are working properly. I cannot apply 'props' like I would if this element was being generated in it's own function component, but yet it is being rendered in that component.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      logicBoard[i] = []
      userBoard[i] = []
      for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        logicBoard[i].push(j)
        userBoard[i].push(<div key={[i]+[j]} className="box" onClick={(e) => this.playerMove(e)}>
          <div className="token"></div>
        </div>)
      }
```

```
playerMove = (e) => {
    console.log(`player move: ${e}`)
}
```

Comment: Which event is causing the issue? The code you pasted seems to involve a click event? Is that the one that is logging undefined?

Comment: Where is your `onHover` event?

Comment: sorry, I changed it to onClick because it was easier for testing purposes. I didn't need it to continually fire as I moved around. Thats the one though. Same results with onClick

Comment: What is the exact error you're receiving, if you're getting one at all?

Comment: not an error, just that 'e' is undefined. I need the value of the mouse event in order to perform the next function. It definitely has something to do with the fact that the divs are being generated in the class component and then passed as props to the function component. I just need the target info